# How to check is my job started or stopped for FluentScheduler .NET

Tags: c#, .net-core, fluentscheduler

How to check if job running for [FluentScheduler](https://github.com/fluentscheduler/FluentScheduler) .NET. I have the following code in the `Startup.cs` class for initializing my job:

```
var registry = new Registry();
registry.Schedule<SendPushesJob>().ToRunNow().AndEvery(60).Seconds();
JobManager.Initialize(registry);
```

and the following code in my controller:

```
public IActionResult StopSender()
{
    JobManager.Stop();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

public IActionResult StartSender()
{
    JobManager.Start();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

I would like to show on the view is my job started or stopped. How I can do this? I can't see the suitable method.

Comment: [Source code](https://github.com/fluentscheduler/FluentScheduler/blob/master/Library/JobManager.cs#L240) shows a `JobManager.RunningSchedules()` that returns *Collection of the currently running schedules*

Comment: There is also the option to get the desired schedule and check its status

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not very elegant way but I have solved it with the following way.

In my controller:

```
public IActionResult StopSender()
{
    JobManager.RemoveAllJobs();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

public IActionResult StartSender()
{
    var registry = new Registry();
    registry.Schedule<SendPushesJob>().ToRunNow().AndEvery(60).Seconds();
    JobManager.Initialize(registry);

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

In the view:

```
<span>
    @if (JobManager.AllSchedules.Any())
    {
        <strong class="text-success">Scheduler is working!</strong>   
    }
    else
    {
        <strong>Scheduler is stopped</strong>   
    }
</span>
```

I think you understand that I have only one job in my project.